# For which functions $f$ does $f''(x)=-f(x)$, where $f''(x)$ denotes the second derivative of $f$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Any linear combination of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ works. I'm wondering if there any others?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A second order linear ODE can only have two linearly independent solutions, so no, there aren't any others.